# How to determine coefficients of the polynomial about $\alpha$ which represent $w \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, polynomials, field-theory, inner-products

Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the field of rationals and $\alpha$ be an irrational number which is not algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then for arbitrary element $w \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$, there exists an unique polynomial $P$ with $P(\alpha)=w$.

My question is the following:

> Given $\alpha$ and $w$, is it possible to determine the polynomial $P$ with 'basic' operations in $\mathbb{R}$, such as addition, multiplication, square root, the limit of some sequences, or etc?

Thinking $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$'s basis as $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \cdots \}$, then the problem is equivalent to:

> Can we represent the ordinary inner product in $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ with respect to basis $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \cdots \}$ with 'basic' operations in $\mathbb{R}$ ?

If then, we can determine coefficients of $P$ by calculating the inner product between $w$ and $\alpha^n$.

If it cannot be represented by 'basic' operations, what other methods or algorithms can be tried to find $P$ or its coefficients?

Comment: When you are given a real number, how do you decide if it belongs to $\Bbb Q[\alpha]$ or not? Also, how do you define $\Bbb Q[\alpha]$? I think the emphasis is on the uniqueness part.

Comment: @Berci I'm thinking $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ as a set of numbers of form $a_n \alpha^n + \cdots +a_0$, and therefore I can assume all $w\in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ as a polynomial of $\alpha$. However, I'm not sure how to compute its concrete form. I thought there may be some cases that we know $w$ is some polynomial of $\alpha$, but not sure what exactly the polynomial is, and we want to know it. In these generic cases, how can we determine the polynomial?

Comment: To actually determine the (coefficients of the) polynomial is much harder than to prove its uniqueness which this exercise is about, and I don't know how to do that. Uniqueness will simply follow from the definition of (not) algebraic number.

Comment: @Berci Actually, my question was not about proving the uniqueness, but about determining the coefficients. I'm not good at English, and maybe that's why you misunderstood, so I tried editing the title. Thank you for the comments.

Comment: In which form would $w$ be given if not the polynomial of $\alpha$? Infinite decimal? Seems impossible what you ask.. Note that $\Bbb Q[\alpha]$ is *dense* in $\Bbb R$ (supposed $\alpha$ is real).